# Christology in Ephesians--what is meant by "the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of glory"?

Tags: grammar, referent-identification, christology, ephesians

Ephesians 1:17:

> That the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of glory, may give unto you the spirit of wisdom and revelation in the knowledge of him: (KJV)

> I keep asking that the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the glorious Father, may give you the Spirit of wisdom and revelation, so that you may know him better. (NIV)

> ἵνα ὁ θεὸς τοῦ κυρίου ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ, ὁ πατὴρ τῆς δόξης, δώῃ ὑμῖν πνεῦμα σοφίας καὶ ἀποκαλύψεως ἐν ἐπιγνώσει αὐτοῦ, (NA 28)

An attempt at disambiguation of the first half of the verse:

It appears that this passage refers to two entities, A & B:

- A is the God of B, A is the Father of glory
- B is our Lord

**Questions**

1. Is the disambiguation of this passage correct? (If not, please suggest corrections)
2. Are the KJV & NIV punctuated correctly, indicating that God the Father is the Father of glory?
3. What is meant by "the God of our Lord" (and why not "the God of us all"?), and does this provide any insight into Paul's Christology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the OP's disambiguation - a grammatical construction in the first clause called "apposition".  In English, an example might be: That car, the red one, is what we will use.  Here "That car" and "the red one" are apposite = two phrases about the same object and BOTH form the subject of the sentence.

In Eph 1:17 we have:

> that the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the glorious Father, may give
> you a spirit of wisdom and revelation in your knowledge of Him.

This is essentially saying:

(1) **that the God of our Lord Jesus Christ** may give you a spirit of wisdom and revelation in your knowledge of Him.

(2) **the glorious Father** may give you a spirit of wisdom and revelation in your knowledge of Him.

and

(3) that the God of our Lord Jesus Christ = the glorious Father

**Appendix**

We often find the Father called Jesus' God in places like Matt 27:46, John 20:17, Rom 15:6, Eph 1:3, 17, 2 Cor 11:31, Heb 1:9, 1 Peter 1:3, Rev 1:6, 3:12

However, the Father also calls Jesus "God" in Heb 1:8.

The Father is also called the one who dwells in glory in places such as:

- John 17:5 - And now, Father, glorify Me in Your presence with the glory I had with You before the world existed.
- 1 John 1:5 - And this is the message we have heard from Him and announce to you: God is light, and in Him there is no darkness at all.

Answer (score 2):

When you reflect on a passage such as this, we all have a ‘foundation’ we ‘work from’.  For this outline, I am obviously outlining mine - for consideration. There are different views, and hopefully some will present them for consideration.

So let’s look at “*the God of our Lord*” - as opposed to the Father of our Lord. Understanding this depends on your [own] understanding of what a ‘god’ is. [Systematic] Theology has [taught] definitions - but just for now, put these to one side, and consider this *definition* - a ‘God’ is your ‘source’. Whatever or whoever your ‘source’ [for whatever your need] is - is your god. And it may vary. At times, yourself - at times something outside of yourself.

For Jesus - his ‘source’ for *everything* was his Father. His ‘father’ was his God. He was ... “*the God of our Lord*”. The same is ‘true’ for us. Who is our ‘source’ of [eternal] life? Who is our ‘source’ for everything we need. Jesus. We access God *through*, Jesus. Believers are ‘in’ Christ - and it is through the finished work of the cross that we have a [new] source for what we need. [Zoe].

Now, in respects to ‘father of glory’ - this is a close translation of the original. ‘Glory’ from the Greek ‘doxa’ - is easily the predominant choice for most translations. And the differing ‘*the glorious Father*’ and ‘*the father of Glory*’ reflect the same ‘truth’. All Glory reflects God, [therefore he is] a ‘glorious’ God. Jesus clearly reflected the Glory of his Father. His father was his only source, so [everything] He [‘did’] fully reflected that Glory.

Your *disambiguation* is correct. And this outline is for *consideration* in respect of the following two points.

Comment: What do you mean by zoe?

Comment: @Michael16 ‘I have come that they may have life {“zoe”}’